# Basic Statistics: Difference between P-Value and Alpha?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I have always considered myself decent at basic statistics but recently, when trying to
explain to a colleague, been troubled by my apparent lack of understanding of a very basic concept: the p-value and $\alpha$.  I understand that $\alpha$ is a property in the design of the experiment (along with the effect size, power and sample size), whereas the p-value is the probability of observing a sample statistic as or more extreme than the one you observed given that your null hypothesis is true.

Where I am confused is that when you do a T-Test, for example, with the exact same inputs as your experiment parameters, why isn’t the p-value equal to $\alpha$?

For example, say we design an experiment as such:

**Experiment Design**

- Two arms, 1:1 ratio with
- $\alpha = .05$
- Power = 80%
- Mean for control is 0
- Effect size is 2
- SE for both groups = 1
- n=4 for each group

Now if you plug these same inputs in a T-Test calculator:

**Control:**

- $\mu=0$
- $SE=1$
- $n=4$

**Experiment:**

- $\mu=2$
- $SE=1$
- $n=4$

, then $p=.02$

Why wouldn’t it equal .05?

Comment: Hi @user123429. The $\alpha$ parameter is the significance value by which you evaluate statistical significance. $\alpha$ can be $\alpha = .01, .05,.10$, depending on the strength of evidence required. However, regardless of the strength of evidence required, your p-value to be less the $\alpha$ to reject the null.

Comment: Hi @EB3112. I understand that, but isn't the whole point of choosing alpha, power, MDE (minimum detectable effect), and sample size such that if your test samples have exactly the MDE then shouldn't it hit the "boundary" on the significance threshold (i.e P = .05)?  (I know I'm wrong, I just don't understand it well enough to understand why I'm wrong.)